# Create an AWS s3 object with information gathered from AWS CDK

Tags: aws-cdk

Imagine creating a website with static javascript assets hosted on S3.

Assume further that the JS would need access to values reserved within CDK the cdk stack such as ARN's of other resources dynamically created from CDK.

What would be the best way to resolve that information, and perhaps package it on a settings file for deployment to some s3 path that the website can load?

Answer (score 1):

You can define fixed name for exportValue, in your case the ARN of the resource, with [CfnOutput](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/latest/docs/@aws-cdk_core.CfnOutput.html) in your cdk

You can retrieve this value with the [List-Exports](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/CloudFormation.html#listExports-property) function of the cloudformation sdk

If you want to, deploy your resources through cdk, create the settings file from the outputs of the cdk (using lambda or codebuild to create file to s3 for example) and deploy a static website (Also cdk) in one pipeline. I would suggest you looking in to [CDK Pipelines](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/developer/cdk-pipelines-continuous-delivery-for-aws-cdk-applications/)